# Make multiple Matlab sessions communicate

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to make multiple Matlab sessions communicate (the session 1 accessing to the workspace of the session 2, for example)?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the parallel computing toolbox, I am not sure what you want to achieve running multiple MATLAB instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways. For example using [sockets](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/using-tcpip-server-sockets.html?refresh=true) or [write to/read from files](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). One instance writes while the other reads, in each case.